# Add text on wordpress admin login page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I want to add a text in admin login page, i searched a lot about this but can't find any thing else a plugin (its my last option).

I also use this filter:

```
function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

But nothing happens; is there any other hook or filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );

function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return 'Your Site Name and Info';
}
```

Codex of [login_message](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_message)

Comment: I think `login_headertitle` is deprecated that is why it did not work.